# java -javaagent: printing java command use guidelines

Tags: java, javaagents, jdk1.7

I'm trying to set a new agent using:

```
java -javaagent:agent.jar
```

When I run I see the java usage message.

MANIFEST.MF:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Created-By: 1.7.0_79 (Oracle Corporation)
Premain-Class: org.mypackage.Agent
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`java` command is used to run some java application. Java agents are not standalone applications that you run directly. They are "added" to your normal application to add some extra behaviour.

So if you have your application packaged as a jar file then you run

```
java -javaagent:agent.jar -jar myApp.jar
```

If you have just a bunch of compiled classes you run something like

```
java -javaagent:agent.jar -cp . my.package.MyMainClass
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you read the '`java`' command documentation? '`class`' or '`-jar file.jar`' arguments are mandatory.

You are running the java command but you are not providing the mandatory command line parameters. Hence the behavior that you experienced.

Comment: You should run 'javac' first. Then after the build is completed, you should run: 'java <YOUR_CLASS_NAME_HERE>'